# Latex rendering error

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, markdown

At least for myself and the original poster, the thread at

[Finding roots of polynomials, negative square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9840/finding-roots-of-polynomials-negative-square-root)

does not render correctly. From OPs post:

"yep tried reloading a few times, the explanation cuts off "there is one solution (the repeated root) and if b^2-4ac" (so you can see part of the markup is probably at fault as i assume this is mid sentence) - c'mon admins help us out! – Aran Mulholland 16 hours ago"

Interestingly it works fine on the preview page, and as far as I know the latex is correct.

Edit: Original is fixed now. The error occurs when using the typing the $\lt$ as opposed to using the latex \lt.

$a \lt b$ vs $a < b$

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced. It seems that while the Markdown doesn't process stuff between `$...$`, even the `<` and `>` are not converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` at all (thus stripped out by the XSS filter) e.g.

> 0<5
>
> ```
> ＄0<5＄
> ```
>
> $0<5$

> 5 < b
>
> ```
> ＄5 < b＄
> ```
>
> $5 <  b$

---

**Edit:** It is fixed. You need to edit your post to see the change.